# Property takagi function by induction.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, continuity, induction

In a lecture on Applied Functional Analysis, the professor showed us some properties of the Takagi function from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1691.pdf). He wrote at the end the following property and said it could be easily done using induction. However, I can not still figure out how.

> Let $$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, \; f(x):= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}d(2^nx)$$
>   be the Takagi function, where $d(x) = \min_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \{ |x-k| \}$. Show that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-y|<1$ holds $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y| \left( 1-\frac{\ln|x-y|}{\ln2} \right).$$

**"The hints":** The inequality holds for $f_m(x):= \sum_{n=0}^m 2^{-n}d(2^nx)$. And consider the operator $[Tf](x) = \frac{1}{2}f(2x)+d(x)$ with the property $f_{m+1} = Tf_m$.

I know that the $f_m$ approach the Takagi function pointwise from below. Then I can take limit pointwise to get the result since this holds for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. [This other paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4205.pdf) at *8.1* shows somehow an approach to this hölder continuity but using $\log_{2}$. However, this is still for me unclear how to come up with this $\ln$ term by induction.

Thanks.

Comment: $\ln(x) /\ln(2)=\log_2 x $

Comment: so simple, so accurate but also so correct. Many thanks.